# why is my c# code so slow

Tags: c#, performance

Tihs is a code that impliments the adaptive histogram equalization algorithm,called by a button in the c# main form, the image is about 1024*768 in size. The problem is this code is too slow ,I don't know where I should modify to improve the performance...Please give me some advice....thanks..

```
private void AHE_BMP_advanced(Int32 halfblocksize)
{
    //adaptive histogram equalization
    Size imgsz = sourceBMP.Size;
    //compute total number of pixels
    double totalNum = imgsz.Height * imgsz.Width;
    //temp image for storation
    Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap(imgsz.Width, imgsz.Height);
    //region statistics
    double[,] prob = new double[256, 3];
    Int32[,] mapping = new Int32[256, 3];
    double[] probSum = new double[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < imgsz.Height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgsz.Width; j++)
        {
            //this.textBox2.Text = "i=" + i.ToString() + "j=" + j.ToString();

            for (int u = 0; u < 256; u++) {
                for (int v = 0; v < 3; v++) {
                    prob[u, v] = 0;
                    mapping[u, v] = 0;
                }
            }

            //produce ahe for this pixel:
            for (int u = i - halfblocksize; u <= i + halfblocksize; u++)
            {
                for (int v = j - halfblocksize; v <= j + halfblocksize; v++)
                {
                    //uv->hi,wi;
                    int hi, wi;
                    hi = u;
                    wi = v;
                    //mirror:
                    if (hi < 0) hi = -hi;
                    else if (hi >= imgsz.Height)
                        hi = 2 * (imgsz.Height - 1) - hi;
                    if (wi < 0) wi = -wi;
                    else if (wi >= imgsz.Width)
                        wi = 2 * (imgsz.Width - 1) - wi;
                    //get hist

                    prob[sBmpdata[wi,hi,0], 0] += 1;
                    prob[sBmpdata[wi,hi,1], 1] += 1;
                    prob[sBmpdata[wi,hi,2], 2] += 1;
                }
            }
            //get ahe value:
            //probSum init:
            probSum[0] = 0;
            probSum[1] = 0;
            probSum[2] = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++)
            {                        
                this.textBox2.Text += "prob[" + k.ToString()+ ",0]=" +
                    prob[k,0].ToString()+"\r\n";

                prob[k, 0] /= totalNum;
                prob[k, 1] /= totalNum;
                prob[k, 2] /= totalNum;
                //Sum
                probSum[0] += prob[k, 0];
                probSum[1] += prob[k, 1];
                probSum[2] += prob[k, 2];
                if(i==40&&j==40)
                //mapping(INT32)
                mapping[k, 0] = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * probSum[0]);
                mapping[k, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * probSum[1]);
                mapping[k, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * probSum[2]);
            }

            tempImg.SetPixel(j, i,
                Color.FromArgb(mapping[sBmpdata[j,i,0], 0],
                mapping[sBmpdata[j,i,1], 1], mapping[sBmpdata[j,i,2], 2]));
        }
    }

    this.pictureBox1.Image = tempImg;

}
```

Comment: Have you tired any profiling tools?

Comment: I found multidimensional arrays `prob[u, v]` to be slow. Try changing them to jagged arrays `prob[u][v]`.

Comment: That look O(n^4),according to the size of halfblocksize and the size of your image, this can be slow.

Comment: reduce looping statements as much as possible

Comment: Without looking at you code: you could use [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to measure parts of your program.

Comment: And use unsave code with pointer arithmetic - it is possible the array access is not optimized and all the checks really cost time in a loop like yours.

Comment: Try to remove `tempImg.SetPixel` and all intercation with form (as TextBox etc) recall this code. I guess this is a problem. And as @amdev said, remove two inner cycles to make O(n^2)

Comment: Make sure you run the method in a separate thread, not blocking the UI. This way it may run for a long time, but the application remains responsive and doesn't irritate the user.

Comment: Also, you're using string concatenation in a loop. That basically creates 256-ish strings! Try using `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: and you also have problems with line  `if(i==40&&j==40)`

Comment: How slow is too slow?

Comment: Extra thing to check: setting `prob` and `mapping` array elements to 0 in a double nested loop can be replaced by a probably much faster `Array.Clear()`.

Comment: "slow" is relative. please give us a time-measurement-value so other users can compare their results with yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SetPixel

`SetPixel` is very slow. Look in to using `LockBits`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has good example.

## String concatenation inside a loop

This line inside a loop is also inefficient as it creates 256 strings for each pixel, so 201 million strings allocated, that's got to be expensive!

```
for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++)
    this.textBox2.Text += "prob[" + k.ToString()+ ",0]=" + prob[k,0].ToString()+"\r\n";
```

**If it's debug, take it out**, 201 million lines of debug text is not useful to you. It you need it you are better off writing to a file as otherwise it's going to take many GB's of ram to store the final string.

Comment: This code have many problems and performance with SetPixel is the smallest here. O(n^3) of string concatenation, for example.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky how do you know, have you profiled the code?

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh SetPixel is very slow, but string concatenation is slower. And shouldn't profile to see asymptotics of it.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky You're right, also the shear amount of RAM required by that final string is immense.

Comment: Even worse, it's not even a string that's being directly concatenated - it's updating a control's Text property with every single update, which just by itself is going to be MANY times slower than just concatenating a string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree to an extent but I don't know about MANY times slower, isn't it just going to set a string field and then call `Invalidate`.

Comment: @weston It calls SendMessage (after doing a few checks) which has a huge overhead, and also raises OnTextChanged() and calls SetWindowText() and does a bunch of other stuff too. The getter is almost as bad.

Comment: @MatthewWatson OK, that's pretty bad! I didn't think how `Invalidate` was implemented.

Comment: @weston It's not Invalidate that does all that - it's the implementation of the `Textbox.Text` and `Control.Text` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Using SetPixel is actually a fairly inefficient way of working with image data. If you want to scan across the whole image I'd suggest manipulating the image data directly using the [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
// Create a new bitmap.
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

// Lock the bitmap's bits.  
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
    bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
    bmp.PixelFormat);

// Get the address of the first line.
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

// Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

// Copy the RGB values into the array.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

// Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.   
for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
rgbValues[counter] = 255;

// Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

// Unlock the bits.
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

// Draw the modified image.
 e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should write

```
    private void AHE_BMP_advanced(Int32 halfblocksize)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = GetAHE_BMP_advanced(halfblocksize, sourceBMP.Size, sBmpdata);
    }
```

where `GetAHE_BMP_advanced` is

```
    private static Bitmap GetAHE_BMP_advanced(int halfblocksize, Size sourceBmpSize, int[,,] sourceBmpData)
    {
        const int m = 256;
        const int n = 3;
        //adaptive histogram equalization
        Size imgsz = sourceBmpSize;
        //compute total number of pixels
        double totalNum = imgsz.Height * imgsz.Width;

        var colors = new Color[sourceBmpSize.Width, sourceBmpSize.Height];
        for (int i = 0; i < imgsz.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < imgsz.Width; j++)
            {
                double[,] prob = new double[m, n];
                int[,] mapping = new int[m, n];

                //produce ahe for this pixel:
                for (int u = i - halfblocksize; u <= i + halfblocksize; u++)
                {
                    for (int v = j - halfblocksize; v <= j + halfblocksize; v++)
                    {
                        int hi = u;
                        int wi = v;
                        //mirror:
                        if (hi < 0) hi = -hi;
                        else if (hi >= imgsz.Height)
                            hi = 2 * (imgsz.Height - 1) - hi;
                        if (wi < 0) wi = -wi;
                        else if (wi >= imgsz.Width)
                            wi = 2 * (imgsz.Width - 1) - wi;
                        //get hist

                        prob[sourceBmpData[wi, hi, 0], 0] += 1;
                        prob[sourceBmpData[wi, hi, 1], 1] += 1;
                        prob[sourceBmpData[wi, hi, 2], 2] += 1;
                    }
                }

                double[] probSum = new double[n];

                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
                {

                    prob[k, 0] /= totalNum;
                    prob[k, 1] /= totalNum;
                    prob[k, 2] /= totalNum;
                    //Sum
                    probSum[0] += prob[k, 0];
                    probSum[1] += prob[k, 1];
                    probSum[2] += prob[k, 2];
                    if (i == 40 && j == 40) //mapping(INT32)
                    {
                        mapping[k, 0] = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * probSum[0]);
                        mapping[k, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * probSum[1]);
                        mapping[k, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * probSum[2]);
                    }
                }

                colors[i, j] = Color.FromArgb(mapping[sourceBmpData[j, i, 0], 0],
                                              mapping[sourceBmpData[j, i, 1], 1],
                                              mapping[sourceBmpData[j, i, 2], 2]);
            }
        }

        return BitmapHelper.CreateBitmap(colors);
    }
```

where BitmapHelper is:

public static class BitmapHelper
    {
        public struct Pixel : IEquatable
        {

```
        // ReSharper disable UnassignedField.Compiler
        public byte Blue;
        public byte Green;
        public byte Red;

        public bool Equals(Pixel other)
        {
            return Red == other.Red && Green == other.Green && Blue == other.Blue;
        }
    }

    public static Color[,] GetPixels(Bitmap two)
    {
        return ProcessBitmap(two, pixel => Color.FromArgb(pixel.Red, pixel.Green, pixel.Blue));
    }

    public static float[,] GetBrightness(Bitmap two)
    {
        return ProcessBitmap(two, pixel => Color.FromArgb(pixel.Red, pixel.Green, pixel.Blue).GetBrightness());
    }

    public static unsafe T[,] ProcessBitmap<T>(Bitmap bitmap, Func<Pixel, T> func)
    {
        var lockBits = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                   bitmap.PixelFormat);
        int padding = lockBits.Stride - (bitmap.Width * sizeof(Pixel));

        int width = bitmap.Width;
        int height = bitmap.Height;

        var result = new T[height, width];

        var ptr = (byte*)lockBits.Scan0;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                var pixel = (Pixel*)ptr;
                result[i, j] = func(*pixel);
                ptr += sizeof(Pixel);
            }
            ptr += padding;
        }

        bitmap.UnlockBits(lockBits);

        return result;
    }

    public static Bitmap CreateBitmap(Color[,] colors)
    {
        const int bytesPerPixel = 4, stride = 8;
        int width = colors.GetLength(0);
        int height = colors.GetLength(1);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[width*height*bytesPerPixel];


        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                bytes[n++] = colors[i, j].R;
                bytes[n++] = colors[i, j].G;
                bytes[n++] = colors[i, j].B;
                bytes[n++] = colors[i, j].A;
            }
        }

        return CreateBitmap(bytes, width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    }

    public static Bitmap CreateBitmap(byte[] data, int width, int height, int stride, PixelFormat format)
    {
        var arrayHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, format, arrayHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        arrayHandle.Free();
        return bmp;
    }
}
```